# Script to count of unique users logged in to remote desktop server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, scripting, rds

I am trying to create a web interface to allow us to monitor how many users are logged in to our 2008r2 terminal server farm. I have a script that is a good starting point and I have tweaked it for our environment, but I need to add some things and I don't know how. I need to get unique logins... here is my starting point....

```
$ComputerList = "RDS1","RDS2","RDS3"
foreach ($ComputerName in $ComputerList){ 
$UserCount=0
$colEvents = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $ComputerName -  
LogName "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-
LocalSessionManager/Operational" |  
Where {$_.ID -eq "21"} |  
Select -Property TimeCreated, Message 
Write-Host "`nServer     Date       Login Time Username"
Foreach ($Event in $colEvents) 
{ 
$EventTimeCreated = $Event.TimeCreated 
$EventMessage = $Event.Message -split "`n" | Select-Object-Index "2"
$EventMessageUser = $EventMessage.Substring(6) 
Write-Host "$ComputerName $EventTimeCreated   $EventMessageUser" 
$UserCount = $UserCount + 1
}
Write-Host "Number of Users: $UserCount"
}
```

….So first things first- How to I get unique logins... Second, how do I get active logins, and third, how do I get the first script into the format of the second script? To get unique logins, Obviously, I would have to have some sort of array that the logins are stored, on the condition that there isn't already that value in the array... but I don't know how. The second would be a matter of matching an ID with one already in the list that doesn't have a logout event.... not sure how to do that either. Any ideas? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd first format the script to a readable state (indenting, line breaks)
and strip it down to only acquire data.

Without your environment taking your tweaking of properties as granted

```
## Q:\Test\2018\11\16\SF_940425.ps1

$ComputerList = "RDS1","RDS2","RDS3"
$data = ForEach ($ComputerName in $ComputerList){
    $colEvents = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $ComputerName `
        -LogName "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational" |
      Where {$_.ID -eq "21"} | Select -Property TimeCreated, Message

    Foreach ($Event in $colEvents){
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            ComputerName     = $ComputerName
            EventTimeCreated = $Event.TimeCreated
            EventMessage     = ($Event.Message -split "`n")[2]
            User             = $EventMessage.Substring(6)
        }
    }
}
$data
$data | Export-Csv '.\ServerUserList.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

And doing an analysis of data lateron with the tools:

- [Sort-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-3.0) (-Unique)
- [Group-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-3.0)
- [Measure-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-3.0)

But I'd try to get a more actual PowerShell version first [than the included PSv2](https://4sysops.com/wiki/differences-between-powershell-versions/)